# How to debug solr indexing

Tags: solr, lucene

I am having trouble getting solr to index my xml files. I am using DIH handle to import the xmls.

Below is part of my xml data file,names hw1.xml

```xml
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Below is my schema file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="ECPS_Schema" version="1.5">
  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="to" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="from" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="heading" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="body" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="text" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <copyField source="to" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="from" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="heading" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="body" dest="text"/>

  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="text_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  </types>
</schema>
```

Below is my data-config file

```xml
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <document>
    <entity name="page" processor="XPathEntityProcessor" stream="true" forEach="/doc" url="/opt/solr-4.4.0/solr/example/exampledocs" forEach="/note" transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer">
      <field column="file" name="id"/>
      <field column="to" xpath="/note/to" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
      <field column="from" xpath="/note/from" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
      <field column="heading" xpath="/note/heading" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
      <field column="body" xpath="/note/body" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I added this to my solrconfig.xml,

```xml
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

My question is since I am using DIH, and the data-config file has url parameter indicating the location of xml files, do I need to do anything else like POST hw1.xml files? Am I correct in assuming that while  creating the core, it sees the dataconfig file and loads the xmls that fit the format described from the directory indicated in the url attribute?

```xml
<entity name="page" processor="XPathEntityProcessor" stream="true" forEach="/doc" url="/opt/solr-4.4.0/solr/example/exampledocs" forEach="/note" transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer">
```

The logs dont indicate error but I see numDocs indexed 0, how to debug this?

Comment: Which version of solr are you using and in which container is your solr running? As you say that you do not see something in the logs, it maybe that you have solr > 4.3 and are _not_ using a jetty. In that case you may have missed that you need to configure logging.

Comment: I have solr 4.4 and i am running it in jetty, running it using start.jar. I havent confgured it any further than example instance comes with.

Comment: When you add a document to solr you should see this document in the console where you started solr from. Also make sure you performed a commit to have the new documents appearing into solr (if auto-commit is set to off)